# I need help adding input fields from a div to another div on a button click

Tags: jquery

I need help adding the input from the fields in my newContainer div to my container div on a button click. This is the extra credit assignment description: 
- Create a form somewhere on the page and style it.
- The Form needs to contain fields for Name, Phone, Email and Address and a submit button.
- When the user clicks the submit button a new student needs to be added to the list, and the search needs to reset and show all students.

I included my HTML below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Assignment 6</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="newContainer">
        <div>
          <p><input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter New Name"/></p>
          <p><input id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Enter Phone #"/></p>
          <p><input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email"/></p>
          <p><input id="address" type="text" placeholder="Enter Address"/></p>
          <button type="button" id="btn1">Add New</button>
        </div>
        <div class="newStudent"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name"/>
      </div>
      <div class="students"></div>
    </div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.1.2/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
     const searchElement = document.querySelector('.search');
    const studentsElement = document.querySelector('.students');
    const newContainer = document.querySelector('.newContainer');

    let students= [];
    console.log(students);

    $("#newContainer").click(contents().appendTo('#container').end().fadeOut());

    let template = `
        {{#each students}}
        <div class="student">
            <p>{{name}}</p>
            <a href="mailto:{{email}}">{{email}}</a>
            <br />
            <a href="tel:{{phone}}">{{phone}}</a>
            <p>{{address}}</p>
            <button class="remove" onclick="removeStudent({{ @index }})">Remove</button>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
    `;


    /**
     * Renders the template with the given data.
     * @param context The date to render.
     */
    function render(context) {
      let compiled = Handlebars.compile(template);
      studentsElement.innerHTML = compiled(context);
    }

    function searchHandler(event) {
      //TODO: 5
      let val = searchElement.value;
      render(template);
      // TODO: 6
        console.log(val);
      let filteredStudents = students.students.filter(function (student) {
          console.log(student.name);
        return student.name.toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase());
    })

      let dataCopy = {
        students: filteredStudents
      };

      render(dataCopy);
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/it238-sp-2019/db-test/students',
      method: 'GET'
     // TODO: 1
    }).done(function (resp) {
      console.log(resp);
      students = {students : resp}
      render(students);
    });
    function removeStudent(index) {
      // TODO: 7
        students.students.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(index);
        searchHandler();

      console.log(students);
    }
// TODO: 4
searchElement.addEventListener('input', searchHandler);
```

So far this is what I have. It's working almost perfect expect I don't want it to loop I want it to only run once so it looks like the other students (attached screenshot). [student](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhzQ6.jpg)

```
var s = $(".students");
$(document).on("click", "#btn1", function() {
  $(".newContainer input").val(function() {
    let n = $("#name");
    let p = $("#phone");
    let e = $("#email");
    let a = $("#address");
    s.append("<div class='student'><p>" + n.val() + "</p><a href='mailto:" + e.val() + "'>" + e.val() + "</a><br /><a href='tel:" + p.val() + "'>" + p.val() + "</a><p>" + a.val() + "</p><button class='remove' onclick='removeStudent()'>Remove</button></div>");
  });
});
```

Template:

```
{{#each students}}
    <div class="student">
        <p>{{name}}</p>
        <a href="mailto:{{email}}">{{email}}</a>
        <br />
        <a href="tel:{{phone}}">{{phone}}</a>
        <p>{{address}}</p>
        <button class="remove" onclick="removeStudent({{ @index }})">Remove</button>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Where is your jQuery?  We need to see your best attempt at solving this problem yourself.

Comment: I don't have much yet for adding the inputs to the div but I added my whole jQuery script to the original post. I don't know where to start.

Comment: @LoganDefoe Is your code up to date? HTML shows `class="students"` but JS shows ` $(".student")`. Missing s in the JS. JS shows `"#btn1"` but there is no matching `id="btn1"` in the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(".newContainer").html()` will grab all the content inside the entire div as HTML.

To grab all the field contents only, each `input` has to be referenced to grab their values using `.val()`. Assuming you want to grab all the inputs in the container, `.each()` can iterate over the set of selected elements.

Edit: Updated to fill in a template per student instead of iterating through each arbitrary field.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#btn1", function() {
  let n = $('#name').val(),
    p = $('#phone').val(),
    e = $('#email').val(),
    a = $('#address').val();

  $(".students").append("<div class='student'><p>" + n + "</p><a href='mailto:" + e + "'>" + e + "</a><br /><a href='tel:" + p + "'>" + p + "</a><p>" + a + "</p><button class='remove' onclick='removeStudent(" + e + ")'>Remove</button></div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="newContainer">
  <div>
    <p><input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter New Name" /></p>
    <p><input id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Enter Phone #" /></p>
    <p><input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" /></p>
    <p><input id="address" type="text" placeholder="Enter Address" /></p>
    <button type="button" id="btn1">Add New</button>
  </div>
  <div class="newStudent"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" />
  </div>
  <div class="students"></div>
</div>
```

A few hopefully helpful tips from updating your attempted code to the working solution:

- Declarations (`let`, `var`, `const`) can use commas to declare multiple variables. This helps save space on JS files and keeps code cleaner.
- `$(".newContainer input")` was only needed when iterating to reference each `input` element under the `.newContainer` element. It is not needed when referencing each element directly by their unique id.
- It is more efficient to call `.val()` once per element during the variable declaration than multiple times during the append. General refactoring and performance consideration.
- It's unclear from your code how you intend to implement `removeStudent()`. I'll leave that for you to give it a shot first. Though I did give you a hint here about using an unique identifier that's readily available ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I'm looking for! How would I go about formatting the information through my template so it is all uniform? I tried to add it in the s.append but it didn't work. I added the template by itself to the end of my original post.

Comment: @LoganDefoe Glad to help. To put it into a specific template, you'll need to reference each `input` individually, plug the `.val()` for each one in between the template html, and `.append()` the template to the container. I'll update this answer. Also, if this is the best fit solution, please mark it as your selected solution :)

Comment: Thank you again for your help! I've almost got it complete but I need to reset the search box and show all students when I press "add new". I have this line of code to make the search box empty because I assumed if it was empty it would show all students but it doesn't for some reason.

`$('input.search[type="text"]').val('');`

Comment: I am also unable to find my newly added object when I search for it.

Comment: @LoganDefoe What does your latest code look like? OP still has lots of "TODO" comments around code that might deal with search and initializing the table. Emptying the `.val()` of the search box does only that -- empty the search box. You'll need additional code to trigger a search (even an empty one). Event handlers like `.on('input',...)` will trigger on manual updates but not programmatic updates.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @OXiGEN, I got it figured out now!